# How to use Map as a part of the page in Sencha touch framework?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using the Sencha Touch framework for the development of my iPad application.

I am in need of using Map as a part of the screen(say half a page). When I try to do put a map component into my page, its covering the full page overlapping the previous components.

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

Easwar

Answer (score 0):

Please post some code to show what you have done / tried yourself so far.

Anyway, I think you're looking for the method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-dockedItems

```
var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
  dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        text: 'Docked to the top'
    }]
  }]
});
```